# When should I use a comma before "even if"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I'm working on this sentence:  "The new rule should not affect section 2607 claims even if the claim does not allege a serious violation."

Do I need a comma before "even if"?  I think "even if" is a subordinating conjunction here and starts an adverbial phrase.  The phrase beginning with "even if" seems nonrestrictive to me so I'd say it needs a comma.  Is that right?

EDIT: Slight change to phrase beginning with "even if" - the real thing is longer and more complex but I over-simplified it.

Comment: Syntactically, the position occupied by *the claim does not allege that a serious violation* should contain text that could in principle stand alone as a complete sentence (but obviously it *doesn't*). The presence (or absence) of a comma is a stylistic choice, imho. Or you could use a dash, or enclose that final element in brackets - whatever floats your boat, as they say.

Comment: I would put a comma there, as the 'even if' phrase is additional information to the 'new rule' phrase. Having said that, I wouldn't declare it absolutely wrong if you choose not to.